# Using a ternary operator to control whether or not to map over state

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a ternary operator to control whether or not you map over allTestTypes. allTestTypes is supposed to be used to populate the options parameter in DropdownSingle

```
{allTestTypes.map(item => item.test_type )}
  {!level ? null :
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{configs[level].name}:</div>
      <DropdownSingle 
        name={configs[level].name} 
        value={testType} 
        options={configs[level].dropdownValues} 
        onChange={onTestFieldUpdate}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  })
```

Update:

```
{!level ? setAllTestTypes.map((item => null :
            <React.Fragment>
              <div>{configs[level].name}:</div>
              <DropdownSingle 
                name={configs[level].name} 
                value={testType} 
                options={configs[level].dropdownValues} 
                onChange={onTestFieldUpdate}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        })
```

Error:

[image]

update 2:

```
{!level ? null : setAllTestTypes.map((item) =>
            <React.Fragment>
              <div>{configs[level].name}:</div>
              <DropdownSingle 
                name={configs[level].name} 
                value={testType} 
                options={item.test_type} 
                onChange={onTestFieldUpdate}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          
          )})
```

Error 2:
[image]

Response:
[image]

Sazzad updated error:
[image]

Comment: You're missing a closing paren on your `map` call. (Before the ':'). But why not `!level ? null : setAllTestTypes.map( ... )`. Skip the map altogether.

Comment: For error 2: you never opened { so you do not need to close them with }

Answer (score 1):

`condition ? functionForMapping : oppositeCase`

You may either place the entire mapping statement here, or just simply wrap it in another function.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Just made an update. Currently getting a syntax error. not to sure what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a condition before mapping any array items:

```
<div>
    {
        !!condition && (
            array.map(item => item /* Mapping Function */)
        )
    }
</div>
```

If you wish to only map certain items use filter:

```
<div>
    {
        array
            .filter(item => !!item /* Condition */)
            .map(item => item /* Mapping Function */)
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a closing `}` .  this should fix it.

```
{!level ? setAllTestTypes.map((item =>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div>{configs[level].name}:</div>
          <DropdownSingle 
            name={configs[level].name} 
            value={testType} 
            options={configs[level].dropdownValues} 
            onChange={onTestFieldUpdate}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }) : null
}
```

Comment: saying there is a syntax token error, I have updated this on my question

Answer (score 0):

`const foo = truthy ? <jsx /> : null` - or - `const foo = truthy && <jsx />`